# MatLab: Saving result and also in which line of which m-file the computation was done

Tags: matlab

I have main.m that goes

```
delete output.txt
diary output.txt
x=1
y=2
a
diary off
```

And a.m contains

```
function [a1, a2] = a(x,y)
   a1=x+y
   a2=x-y
   while a1<5
      a1=a1+1
   end
```

I want MatLab to save an output txt file that has every computational result TOGETHER with at which line of which m-file the computation was done:

```
x=1
    main.m, line 3 
y=2
    main.m, line 4
a1 = 3
    a.m, line 2
a2 = -1
    a.m, line 3
a1 = 4
    a.m, line 5
a1 = 5
    a.m, line 5
```

I haven't heard about standard way of doing this. But if there is any undocumented way of doing this, this will make debugging extremely convenient. Does anyone have idea?

Comment: You can simply [step through the execution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html#buvyxwy) of the program, which is the best way to debug.

Comment: It is not the right way to debug a code, but you can try [echo on all](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/echo.html). Remember to set `echo off all` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The easist way to do this is to display your result
Function `disp`in Matlab - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/disp.html

You just need to come-up with a framework of output results.
For example, using your code example:

```
If x==1
disp('main.m - line 3')
elseif y==2
disp('main.m - line 4')
elseif a1==3
disp('a.m, line 2')
elseif a2==-1
disp('a.m, line 3')
elseif a1==4
disp('a.m, line 5')
elseif a1==5
disp('a.m, line 5')
end
```

This is of course a workaround but I think you can get the idea behind this

Comment: Thank you. But there are more than 5000 lines in my project so it can't be my option..

Comment: well... that won't be easy to do directly